# Find missing URL routes using the command-line

Tags: unix, grep, url-routing, pipe, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to automate a check for missing routes a Play! web application. 
The routing table is in a file in the following format:

```
GET /home          Home.index
GET /shop          Shop.index
```

I've already managed to use my command line-fu to crawl through my code and make a list of all the actions that should be present in the file. This list is in the following format:

```
Home.index
Shop.index
Contact.index
About.index
```

Now I'd like to pipe the output of this text into another command that checks if each line is present in the route file. I'm not sure how to proceed though.

The result should be something like this:

```
Contact.index
About.index
```

Does someone have a helpful suggestion on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$NF];next}!($0 in a)' routes.txt list.txt
```

**EDIT**

if you want the above line to accept `list` from stdin:

```
cat list.txt|awk 'NR==FNR{a[$NF];next}!($0 in a)' routes.txt -
```

replace `cat list.txt` with your *magic command*

Comment: Nice, this works when a output the list into a file. But is it also possible to pipe the content of list.txt into this command? Something like awk '...' routes.txt `<another command to build the list>` or awk '...' routes.txt | <another command> ?